# Displaying max value in bottom of the pie chart - highcharts

Tags: vue.js, highcharts

I am using highchart. I want to display the maximum value and value label at the bottom of the pie chart.[please see the attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmHty.png). if the maximum value is equal display both value and that label.

```
this.pieChart.push(
                      {
                        chart: {
                          type: 'pie',
                          options3d: {
                            enabled: true,
                            alpha: 45
                          }
                        },
                        title: {
                          text: 'Question Title'
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                          text: ''
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                          pie: {
                            innerSize: 100,
                            depth: 45,
                            dataLabels: {
                              enabled: true,
                              format: '<b></b><br>{point.percentage:.1f} %',
                              distance: -50,
                              filter: {
                                property: 'percentage',
                                operator: '>',
                                value: 4
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        },
                        series: [{
                          name: 'Answer Selected',
                          data: [
                              ['1st Que ans - 1', 3],
                              ['1st Que ans - 2', 2],
                              ['1st Que ans - 3', 1],
                              ['1st Que ans - 4', 2]
                          ]
                        }]
                      })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to render a custom label base on the included data and using the `render` callback. The instruction what is happening is in the code. If something is unclear - feel free to ask.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/euLyc49j/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this,
      max = Math.max(...chart.series[0].processedYData);

    chart.series[0].points.forEach(p => {
      if (p.y === max) {
        if (p.customLabel) {
          p.customLabel.destroy();
        }
                    
        //render label in the (0, 0)
        p.customLabel = chart.renderer.label(p.name + ' - ' + p.y , 0, 0)
          .css({
            color: '#FFFFFF'
          })
          .attr({
            fill: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75)',
            padding: 8,
            r: 5,
            zIndex: 6
          })
          .add();
        // position label in the bottom center
        p.customLabel.translate(chart.plotWidth / 2 - p.customLabel.getBBox().width / 2, chart.plotSizeY + chart.plotTop)
      }
    })
  }
}
```

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#label

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render

Comment: I hope you are well and safe and thank you for helping. right now if 2 or more answers value is the same they are overlapping on each other. And if the answer name is too long, then the answer name is not breaking.[screenshot 1](https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/5251209/e4f479021b61da1b2ba216558152be03)

Comment: In this case, you will need to create and add some custom logic to detect if the label has been created - if so, you will need to create the next one in the different place.